# Redux - understanding combine reducers

Tags: javascript, redux, functional-programming

I am working on a tutorial about Redux, and I am trying to figure out this piece of code:

```
export const combineReducers = (config) =>{
    return (state, action) => {
        return Object.keys(config).reduce((state, key) => {
            const reducer = config[key];
            const previousState = state.get(key);
            const newValue = reducer(previousState, action);

            if (!newValue) {
                throw new Error(`A reducer returned undefined when reducing key::"${key}"`);
            }
            return state.set(key, newValue);
        }, state);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how is all of this connected. I have a `index.js` file in `reducers` folder, that calls `combineReducers`.

```
export const reducer = combineReducers({
    currentUser
});
```

The `currentUser` that I am passing as a config parameter looks like this:

```
export const currentUser = createReducer(null, {
    [UPDATE_STATUS](state,action) {
        return state.set(`status`,action.status);
    }
});
```

And this is the createReducer function:

```
export const createReducer = (initialState, handlers)=>{
    return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
        if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
            return handlers[action.type](state, action)
        } else {
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

So, we are passing the `createReducer` that returns reducer function to `combineReducers`. So, at this point we end up with something like this I assume:

```
export const combineReducers = (config) =>{
    // this is just for demonstration purposes, to show what I assume ends up as a config argument
    // config = {
    //     currentUser: function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    //                     if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
    //                         return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    //                     } else {
    //                         return state
    //                     }
    //                 }
    //  }
    // where function reducer has access to parameters that were passed previously
    // initialState = null
    // handlers = {
    //     [UPDATE_STATUS](state,action) {
    //         return state.set(`status`,action.status);
    //      }
    //  }

    return (state, action) => {
        return Object.keys(config).reduce((state, key) => {
            const reducer = config[key];
            const previousState = state.get(key);
            const newValue = reducer(previousState, action);

            if (!newValue) {
                throw new Error(`A reducer returned undefined when reducing key::"${key}"`);
            }
            return state.set(key, newValue);
        }, state);
    }
}
```

But I don't see where do we pass `state` and `action` and call that function that `combineReducers` return?
Would very much appreciate if anyone would clear this up, and show where the actual call is being made.

Comment: we're passing a function

Comment: Your last piece of code is invalid. Even if it were it makes little sense. For example you are immediately reassigning function argument to something different. Why?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, that was just for demonstration purposes, to show what I assume ends up as a config argument.

Comment: @Leff `config` argument inside `combineReducers` is expected to be an object which all properties are functions. `currentUser ` is a function. But when you do `combineReducers({currentUser})` you actually making an object with a single property `combineReducers({ currentUser: currentUser })`.

Comment: As of "I don't see where do we pass state and action" You are exporting reducer function `export const reducer` later to be used when you create a store. Passing `state` and `action` is done by redux lib code when you dispatch an action.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko So, does the passing of state and action happen somewhere in the createStore function then?```createStore(reducer,defaultState,applyMiddleware(createLogger({
    stateTransformer:state=>state.toJS()
})))```

Comment: Well, yes and no. Reducer will be called once when you create a store to populate initial state [src](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L261) but this action wont be handled by your "real" code. So actual calls to business logic inside reducer will happen when you dispatch an action of known type say `UPDATE_STATUS` and redux infrastructure will pass current state and action to it.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Ok, so, that "magic" happens in the redux code, if I understood correctly? Thank you for your explanations!